# Как скопировать файлы из массива?

Tags: c++

Только вникаю не судите =)

Итак у меня есть 3 файла которые нужно скопировать из пункта E в пунт D.

Как решить эту задачу?

```
std::string MassiveFiles[3] = {"1.txt","2.txt","3.txt"}; // или как правильно записать?
for (int i = 0; MassiveFiles; i++)
{
    CopyFile("E:\\откуда", "D:\\куда", 0);  
}
```

Comment: Так в чём собственно вопрос? Имена файлов в какой кодировке? Какая файловая система и какая кодировка там? Как распознаются глифы на ней? Ну и т.д., и т.п...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Объявление массива с именами файлов

Имена файлов для копирования можно хранить в массиве, как у вас:

```
string files[3] = {"one.txt", "two.txt", "three.txt"};
```

причём если массив при объявлении сразу инициализируется, то размер можно не указывать:

```
string files[] = {"one.txt", "two.txt", "three.txt"};
```

или можно хранить имена файлов в [векторе](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (вектор более гибок, его размер можно изменять, также его удобней передавать в функции):

```
vector<string> files = {"one.txt", "two.txt", "three.txt"};
```

#### 2. Итерирование по массиву/вектору

- Самый простой способ — итерироваться используя индексы. Если число элементов известно, то условие завершения цикла можно записать как `i < число_элементов`:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      string file = files[i];
      // дальше работаем с переменной `file`
  ```

  Если число элементов неизвестно, то в случае вектора его можно получить используя метод [`vector::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size):

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i) {
      string file = files[i];
      // дальше работаем с переменной `file`
  ```
- Также есть сокращённая удобная форма итерирования без индексов:

  ```
  for (string file : files) {
      // дальше работаем с переменной `file`
  ```

#### 3. Копирование файлов

Кажется тут здесь достаточно получить строки пути-источника и пути-назначения, это можно сделать с помощью конкатенации:

```
string source = "E:\\" + file;
string destination = "D:\\" + file;
```

Дальше эти переменные можно передать в функцию копирования файлов:

```
CopyFile(source.c_str(), destination.c_str(), false);
```

[Полный код на Ideone](https://ideone.com/Maai3k)

Comment: Что делать, если имена файлов в кодировке, которую целевая ФС не поддерживает?

Comment: @0andriy к сожалению я не знаю

Comment: @diraria, В `string file = files[i];` - выражение должно иметь константное значение. Как быть?

Comment: @GooliveR не очень понял ошибку, думаю задать ещё один вопрос, в котором привести [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и полный код ошибки будет оптимальным решением

Comment: Я к тому, что в вашем ответе было бы неплохо сделать сноску на этот счёт. Я не знаю, сколько возможных вариантов у Windows (наверное, два как минимум), и если возникнет ошибка, то стоит либо как-то уведомить пользователя, либо попытаться перекодировать.

Comment: @diraria, проблема решилась) простая невнимательность к коду =). А можно ли как-нибудь пути соединить с помощью `PathCombine?` И нужен ли он вообще ?

Comment: @0andriy, да, было бы неплохо. Но я к сожалению не знаю тонкостей работы с кодировками имён файлов. Если вы знаете, то при желании можете опубликовать ещё один ответ с описанием этого

Comment: @GooliveR, думаю можно. Но, мне кажется, что это другой вопрос. Соответственно мне кажется что [стоит его задать другим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

Из выше предложенного решения, я решил немного изменить его и добавил функцию [PathCombine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb773571(v=vs.85).aspx)
В итоге всё скопировалось как нужно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Shlwapi.h"

#pragma comment(lib,"ShLwApi.Lib") // для PathCombine

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> files = { "one.txt", "two.txt", "three.txt" };
    TCHAR t1Dir[MAX_PATH + 2] = { 0 };
    TCHAR t2Dir[MAX_PATH + 2] = { 0 };
    for (auto file : files) {
        auto source = PathCombine(t1Dir, "E:\\", file.c_str());
        auto destination = PathCombine(t2Dir, "D:\\", file.c_str());
        CopyFile(source, destination, false);
    }
    return 0;
}
```